# Adding DateTime field to many-to-many EF Code First relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, fluent

I am using EF 6 Code-First, table per type, and I have two concrete classes `Group` and `User`. `Group` has a navigation property `Members` which contains a collection of `User`. I have mapped this many-to-many relationship in EF using Fluent syntax:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>
    .HasMany<User>(g => g.Members)
    .WithMany(u => u.Groups);
```

I would like to be able to say *when* a member has joined a group so that I can query for, say, the newest member(s). I am not sure of how this is best accomplished within the framework.

I see the following options:

1. Create and use an audit table (ie `GroupMembershipAudit` consisting of `Group`, `User`, join/unjoin, and `DateTime`
2. Add a column to the autogenerated many-to-many table between `User` and `Group`

Is there anything within EF to facilitate this sort of storage of many-to-many historical info like this / append columns to the many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add a column to the autogenerated many-to-many table between User and
>   Group

That is not possible - auto-generated junction tables can contain only keys (that is called Pure Join Table). According to [Working with Many-to-Many Data Relationships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742359%28VS.100%29.aspx) article: If the join table contains fields that are not keys, the table is not a PJT and therefore Entity Framework cannot create a direct-navigation (many-to-many) association between the tables. (Join tables with non-key fields are also known as join tables with payload.)

> Create and use an audit table (ie GroupMembershipAudit consisting of
>   Group, User, join/unjoin, and DateTime

Actually you should create `GroupMembershipAudit` entity. With Code First table will be generated, you don't need to create it manually.

Comment: Thanks Sergey - I wasn't sure if there was anything magical baked into EF to facilitate history of many-to-many tables, now I know there is not